# How to chain RethinkDB filters in PHP

Tags: php, filter, rethinkdb

I'm needing to create more than 1 filter to run a query to cut down the number of results found.

I am trying to do these 3 queries at once using RethinkDB for php found [here](https://github.com/danielmewes/php-rql/)

**The code I am running is:**

```
    $query = \r\table('payments')->filter(
        \r\row('forwarded')->eq('1'),
        \r\row('bad_callbacks_sent')->lt("1"),
        \r\row('confirmations')->le('7')
    )->run($this->conn);
```

I've just also tried doing the following and it doesn't work (it's just showing all where the first argument - where forwarded = 1. It's only doing the first filter:

```
     $query = \r\table('payments')
    ->filter(\r\row('forwarded')->eq('1'))
    ->filter(\r\row('bad_callbacks_sent')->lt("6"))
    ->filter(\r\row('confirmations')->le("7"))
    ->run($this->conn);
```

But it doesn't seem to be doing what I ask.
I need to make it get:

1. Where forwarded == 1
2. Where bad_callbacks_sent < 1
3. Where confirmations <= 7

I found this the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720145/rethinkdb-chaining-combining-filters), which shows that you can chain them in js but I'm wondering about PHP:

```
r.db('items').table('tokens')
.filter(r.row('valid_to').gt(r.now()))
.filter(r.row["processed"] == False)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out, the issue was not with my new code:

```
    $query = \r\table('payments')
    ->filter(\r\row('forwarded')->eq('1'))
    ->filter(\r\row('bad_callbacks_sent')->lt(6))
    ->filter(\r\row('confirmations')->le(7))
    ->run($this->conn);
```

But with the variable type.
In my database, it was stored as an int but I was trying to read it via (le("7")) a string.

The above code works fine :)
It allows you to filter more than 1 query in retihnkdb for php.

Make sure you check your variable types in your database!
RethinkDB is very sensitive to what types they're.

Hope I save you some time.